# Workaround for Netty's single-thread per handler/channel restriction

Tags: netty

In Netty 4, there is the [restriction](http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.x.html#wiki-h2-33): "`EventExecutor` and `EventLoop` assigned to a handler or a channel are always single-threaded." This looks good for thread safety, but not so good for throughput in case of dealing with hundreds of connections. Some events might be waiting in a queue while there are idle threads to process them. In my researching, I found related [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/netty/1kAS-FJWGRE) and [issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1912), but got so confused with event loops, groups, executors and invokers that could not understand how to use them to get what I want.

I have a set of handlers to encode and decode data and to redirect incomming messages to akka system. Some messages are big and it takes valuable time to serialize/deserialize them. I want this handlers not to wait for specific thread, just do they work in first available thread in the pool.

Can I do this with Netty 4? Or should I use version 5.0.0Alpha1 witch is not declared as stable? Is this really an issue?

Here is the code:

```
bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1, new NamedThreadFactory("SocketServerBossExecutor"));
workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(NUMBER_OF_WORKER_THREADS, new NamedThreadFactory("SocketServerWorkerExecutor"));

serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
        .group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
        .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
        .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
                ch.pipeline()
                        //Decoder
                        .addLast("frameDecoder", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(MAX_FRAME_LENGTH, LENGTH_FIELD_OFFSET, LENGTH_FIELD_LENGTH, LENGTH_ADJUSTMENT, INITIAL_BYTES_TO_STRIP))
                        .addLast("protobufDecoder", PROTOBUF_DECODER)
                        .addLast("protoMessageDecoder", PROTO_MESSAGE_DECODER)

                        //Encoder
                        .addLast("frameEncoder", FRAME_ENCODER)
                        .addLast("protobufEncoder", PROTOBUF_ENCODER)
                        .addLast("protoMessageEncoder", PROTO_MESSAGE_ENCODER)

                        .addLast("handler", upstreamHandler);
            }
        })
```

**UPD**: I will also prefer not to bind I/O operations with different channels to the same thread if it is possible.